# wpdb query gives back a wrong result

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've written some code in my PHP snippet which is on my WordPress page and the wpdb query gives me always  a wrong result.

In WordPress

```
$column07a = $_POST[$attributes[8]];         **<-** echo displayed **24253**

$queryColumn07 = $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT DISTINCT p.id 
                        FROM plz p 
                            LEFT JOIN vermieter v ON v.id_plz=p.id 
                        WHERE p.postleitzahl='$column07a' " );`     

$column07 = $wpdb->query( $queryColumn07 ); **<-** echo displayed **1**
```

**In SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id 
FROM plz p 
    LEFT JOIN vermieter v ON v.id_plz=p.id 
WHERE p.postleitzahl='24253';
```

phpmyadmin displayed **3** which is the correct result for that query

What did I do wrong? May you help me in someway?

Comment: When you run query `$queryColumn08`, is this defined somewhere else as the previous line is for `$queryColumn07`.

Comment: Sorry I corrected my spelling  mistake.

Comment: Side note: that's not the proper way to use `$wpdb->prepare()`. For it to do what's supposed to do you should use it like this instead: `$wpdb->prepare( " SELECT DISTINCT p.id FROM plz p LEFT JOIN vermieter v ON v.id_plz=p.id WHERE p.postleitzahl=%s ", $column07a );`. The way you have it now leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks. See [wpdb::prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference%2Fclasses%2Fwpdb%2Fprepare%2F/) for more details.

Comment: I know, I just left it that way so you guys do not have to decrypt the statement. Easier to read for y'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `1` as a result is because you're using the `query()` method instead of [get_results()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) or [get_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/).

From the [$wpdb::query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/#return) documentation:

> **Return:**
>
> (*int*|*bool*) Boolean true for CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE and DROP queries. **Number of rows affected/selected for all other queries**. Boolean false on error.

(Emphasis mine.)

So, when you run this:

```
$column07 = $wpdb->query( $queryColumn07 );
```

You get `1` because `query()` is returning the number of rows found by your `SELECT` query.

In your specific case, as pointed out earlier, you want to use [get_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/) instead to get the actual ID returned by the query:

```
$column07 = $wpdb->get_var( $queryColumn07 );

echo $column07; // Should output 3 according to your comments.
```